# City specific result in google for searches from different city for generic keyword?

Tags: seo, google, local-seo

Is is possible to configure my website to show different content in search result for the user from same google domain but from different cities?
When I search in google.co.in from my city Chennai for the generic keywords like 'part time jobs', I get search results like 'Part time jobs in Chennai' for different websites. 
Are those website manipulate it or this is solely in the hands of Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Google shows local searches from Chennai for the keyword "Part time jobs" because it believes if you search for this keyword, you're looking for a job near you. This behaviour is solely in the hands of Google.

But you can optimize your website in such a way that your website will show up in these results:

1. Add the name of the city to the title and the description of your pages
2. Make sure the address of the company is in this region and add this address on each page of the website.
3. Add a landline with a zipcode from this region on each page of the website.
4. Add the name of the city to the content, alt-texts of images, images-names.
5. Create a Google business-page and verify your address.
6. Add your business to Google Maps.

If your business has multiple stores than you can create a page for each store to feature that location. (ex coffee shops)

1. Show the address and the landline of the store on his page.
2. Make sure to write unique content for each store to avoid being flagged as duplicate content. (about 300 words of unique content)

The problem gets harder but the idea stays the same when your business covers multiple locations but has no physical store in these locations. (ex. a construction firm that covers 3-4 adjacent cities). What you can do in this case is for example create a page with testimonials for each city.